# How to get version attribute from a gradle build to be included in runtime Swing application

Tags: java, swing, groovy, gradle

I have a simple parent project with modules/applications within it. My build tool of choice is gradle. The parent `build.gradle` is defined below.

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    version "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

What I would like to do is utilize the version attribute (0.1.0-SNAPSHOT) within my swing application. Specifically, I'd like it to display in the titlebar of the main JFrame. I expect to be able to do something like `this.setTitle("My Application - v." + ???.version);`

The application is a plain java project, but I'm not opposed to adding groovy support it it will help.

Comment: some [`.properties`](http://crunchify.com/java-properties-file-how-to-read-config-properties-values-in-java/) file that gets the version set dynamically (like example 1-8 in https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/gradle-beyond-the/9781449373801/ch01.html )?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I like creating a properties file during the build. Here's a way to do that from Gradle directly:

```
task createProperties(dependsOn: processResources) {
  doLast {
    new File("$buildDir/resources/main/version.properties").withWriter { w ->
        Properties p = new Properties()
        p['version'] = project.version.toString()
        p.store w, null
    }
  }
}

classes {
    dependsOn createProperties
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. But my setup got an error on `project.buildTimestamp`... and looking at the current Gradle Javadoc and DSL docs I can see no sign of any such method for `Project` or any other class.  Version is 2.14, presumably that's the reason.  Have no idea how to do such a time stamp now, do you?  Care to update your answer?

Comment: Apparently `project.buildTimestamp` was a figment of my imagination. You can still add other properties based upon your needs, but they aren't relevant to this example, so I've removed it from the answer.

Comment: Nothing wrong with wishing the world were better than it is ;-).  But thanks for removing a source of potential confusion!

Comment: Please extend the answer with how the user's supposed to read the generated file in runtime. Otherwise it does not fully address the question asked.

Comment: The details of the (Java Properties API)[ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html] should be understood by any Java programmer, so I didn't clutter up the answer with unnecessary details.

Comment: Let's make this explicit: To get the properties runtime you need to annotate your class with `@PropertySource({"classpath:version.properties"})`
Then you can assign a property to a private variable with annotation like:
`@Value("${gitLastTag}")`
`private String gitLastTag;`

Comment: @isgoed You do realize that `@PropertySource` is a Spring annotation, not a Java annotation, right? Why are you dragging Spring into a discussion of Gradle?

Comment: `Project#buildDir` is deprecated since gradle >8.2. You can use `project.layout.buildDirectory` instead. Full line of code: `project.layout.buildDirectory.file("resources/main/version.properties").get().asFile`

Answer (score 23):

You can always use brute force as somebody suggested and generate properties file during build. More elegant answer, which works only partially would be to use

```
getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion()
```

Problem is that this will work only if you run your application from generated jar - if you run it directly from IDE/expanded classes, getPackage above will return null. It is good enough for many cases - just display 'DEVELOPMENT' if you run from IDE(geting null package) and will work for actual client deployments.

Comment: Thanks... Yes, in fact I suggest you need to use yours for deployment, and Craig Trader's solution during testing... for which reason the path to version.properties in his answer should be ".../resources/***TEST***/version.properties".  No need to clutter up your deployed jar with this file.

Comment: This doesn't work from a generated jar file I just tried it.

Comment: Please check if your manifest inside jar contains version. I think it takes it from there, maybe you are using slightly different way of packing jar, which omits it.

Comment: Add this to "build.gradle": ```manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.example.hello.World',
                'Implementation-Version': version
        )
    }```

Answer (score 12):

Better idea is to keep the project version in `gradle.properties` file. All the properties from this file will be automatically loaded and can be used in `build.gradle` script.

Then if you need the version in your swing application, add a `version.properties` file under `src/main/resources` folder and filter this file during application build, [here](http://jlorenzen.blogspot.com/2013/06/resource-filtering-with-gradle.html) is a post that shows how it should be done.

`version.properties` will be included in the final jar, hence can be read and via `ClassLoader` and properties from this file can be displayed in application.

Comment: Resource filtering is great solution. It separates concerns allowing the build tool to provide the details it knows. see [gradle docs](https://guides.gradle.org/migrating-from-maven/#resource_filtering)
```processResources {
    expand(version: version, buildNumber: currentBuildNumber)
}```

Answer (score 4):

Simpler and updated solution of @Craig Trader (ready for Gradle 4.0/5.0)

```
task createProperties {
    doLast {
        def version = project.version.toString()
        def file = new File("$buildDir/resources/main/version.txt")
        file.write(version)
    }
}

war {
    dependsOn createProperties
}
```

Comment: Writing a plain text file is simpler than writing a properties file, but not as useful in the long run, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I used @Craig Trader's answer, but had to add quite some changes to make it work (it also adds git-details):

```
task createProperties() {
    doLast {
        def details = versionDetails()
        new File("$buildDir/resources/main/version.properties").withWriter { w ->
            Properties p = new Properties()
            p['version'] = project.version.toString()
            p['gitLastTag'] = details.lastTag
            p['gitCommitDistance'] = details.commitDistance.toString()
            p['gitHash'] = details.gitHash.toString()
            p['gitHashFull'] = details.gitHashFull.toString() // full 40-character Git commit hash
            p['gitBranchName'] = details.branchName // is null if the repository in detached HEAD mode
            p['gitIsCleanTag'] = details.isCleanTag.toString()
            p.store w, null
        }
        // copy needed, otherwise the bean VersionController can't load the file at startup when running complete-app tests.
        copy {
            from "$buildDir/resources/main/version.properties"
            into "bin/main/"
        }
    }
}
classes {
    dependsOn createProperties
}
```

And load it from the constructor of class: VersionController

```
import static net.logstash.logback.argument.StructuredArguments.v;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.info.BuildProperties;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;

@RestController
public class VersionController {

    final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppInfoController.class);

    private Properties versionProperties = new Properties();

    private String gitLastTag;
    private String gitHash;
    private String gitBranchName;
    private String gitIsCleanTag;

    VersionController()
    {
        String AllGitVersionProperties = "";
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("classpath:/version.properties");

        if(inputStream == null)
        {
            // When running unit tests, no jar is built, so we load a copy of the file that we saved during build.gradle.
            // Possibly this also is the case during debugging, therefore we save in bin/main instead of bin/test.
            try {
                inputStream = new FileInputStream("bin/main/version.properties");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try {
            versionProperties.load(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            AllGitVersionProperties += e.getMessage()+":";
            log.error("Could not load classpath:/version.properties",e);
        }

        gitLastTag = versionProperties.getProperty("gitLastTag","last-tag-not-found");
        gitHash = versionProperties.getProperty("gitHash","git-hash-not-found");
        gitBranchName = versionProperties.getProperty("gitBranchName","git-branch-name-not-found");
        gitIsCleanTag = versionProperties.getProperty("gitIsCleanTag","git-isCleanTag-not-found");

        Set<Map.Entry<Object, Object>> mainPropertiesSet = versionProperties.entrySet();
        for(Map.Entry oneEntry : mainPropertiesSet){
            AllGitVersionProperties += "+" + oneEntry.getKey()+":"+oneEntry.getValue();
        }
         log.info("All Git Version-Properties:",v("GitVersionProperties", AllGitVersionProperties));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @Craig Trader's solution to save the properties in a version.properties file. Add to build.gradle:

```
task createProperties() {
    doLast {
        def details = versionDetails()
        new File("$buildDir/resources/main/version.properties").withWriter { w ->
            Properties p = new Properties()
            p['version'] = project.version.toString()
            p['gitLastTag'] = details.lastTag
            p['gitCommitDistance'] = details.commitDistance.toString()
            p['gitHash'] = details.gitHash.toString()
            p['gitHashFull'] = details.gitHashFull.toString() // full 40-character Git commit hash
            p['gitBranchName'] = details.branchName // is null if the repository in detached HEAD mode
            p['gitIsCleanTag'] = details.isCleanTag.toString()
            p.store w, null
        }
        // copy needed, otherwise the bean VersionController can't load the file at startup when running complete-app tests.
        copy {
            from "$buildDir/resources/main/version.properties"
            into "bin/main/"
        }
    }
}
classes {
    dependsOn createProperties
}
```

To load the properties runtime in version.properties you need to annotate your class with `@PropertySource({"classpath:version.properties"})`
Then you can assign a property to a private variable with annotation like:

```
@Value("${gitLastTag}")
private String gitLastTag;
```

Full example:

```
package com.versioncontroller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import java.util.Properties;

@PropertySource({"classpath:version.properties"})
public class VersionController {

    @Value("${gitLastTag}")
    private String gitLastTag;
    @Value("${gitHash}")
    private String gitHash;
    @Value("${gitBranchName}")
    private String gitBranchName;
    @Value("${gitIsCleanTag}")
    private String gitIsCleanTag;

    @PostConstruct  // properties are only set after the constructor has run
    private void logVersion(){

        // when called during the constructor, all values are null.
        System.out.println("All Git Version-Properties:");
        System.out.println("gitLastTag: " + gitLastTag),
        System.out.println("gitHash: " + gitHash),
        System.out.println("gitBranchName: " + gitBranchName),
        System.out.println("gitIsCleanTag: " + gitIsCleanTag));
    }
}
```